# To find the inverse function

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

I have the following function,
$$f(m)  = a\left( {-m \ \exp(-2m) \over 2} - {\exp(-2m)\over 4} + {1 \over 4} \right) $$
where $m \ge 0$, $<m>$ = 1 and $a$ is just a constant 
[image] 
and I want to re-arrange this function such that, $$m = F(f(m))$$ Where $F$ is a function of $f(m)$.

I have made some progress in solving the above problem but I am stuck at a step. I have types my progress below.
$$f(m)  = a\left( {-m \ \exp(-2m) \over 2} - {\exp(-2m)\over 4} + {1 \over 4} \right)$$
$${4 \times f(m) \over a} - 1 = \left( {-2 \times m \ \exp(-2m) } - {exp(-2m)}  \right)$$
$${4 \times f(m) \over a} - 1 = \left( {-2 \times m \  } - 1  \right) \times \exp(-2m)$$
I did try taking a log but it did not take me anywhere. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+function+a%5Cleft%28+%7B-m+%5C+exp%28-2m%29+%5Cover+2%7D+-+%7Bexp%28-2m%29%5Cover+4%7D+%2B+%7B1+%5Cover+4%7D+%5Cright%29

Comment: Here is a [series solution to your inverse function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/InversionFormulas.html). You just have to figure out the convergence, plug in a few things, and simplify. Also try the [Fourier inverse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem), [General Series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html), and [Mellin inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) theorems. You could also try a recursive definition.

Comment: What do you mean by $m \ge 0$ and $<m> = 1$ ? Usually this kind of notation means "average value of $m$" equals $1$...

Comment: Closely related question from same user: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240785/is-a-2-left-x-exp-2x-over-2-exp-2x-over-4-1-over-4-right

Comment: @ErikSatie your input in WA is incorrect. Helping WA a little bit, it finds a solution (ignoring the term $a$, WLOG): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+function+%7B-m+exp%28-2m%29+%5Cover+2%7D+-+%7Bexp%28-2m%29%5Cover+4%7D+%2B+%7B1+%5Cover+4%7D+ The trick is to use the Lambert function $W(x)$ which is the inverse of $x\exp(x)$. In your case, just factor the $\exp(-2m)$ term. Moreover, divide and multiply by $\exp(-1)$ such that you obtain something like $(-2m-1)\exp(-2m-1)$ and then use the Lambert function.

Comment: @FeedbackLooper, in WA, the inverse function is given. I can use that right?

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes. it refers to the average.

Comment: I don't understand why you are mentionning an average value for $m$. Your question - as far as I understand it - is a pure analysis issue without connection with probability...

Comment: Yes you can use it. Just be careful about which branch of the Lambert function you use. You may need to use either the principal branch $W_0$ or the alternative branch $W_{-1}$

Comment: Please, say why you mention that the average value of m is 1.